# Is it possible to pass additional arguments with the model in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using the script bellow to pass a strong typed model and it is working fine. Is there a way to also include, with the model, the value of the vars, as additional arguments? I know how to pass either the model or the vars, but not both.

```
var sample1 = "aaa";
var sample2 = "bbb";

    $.ajax({

   url: "Action/Controller",
   data: $("#form123").serialize(),       
   cache: true,
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'html',                                
   success: function (data) {                       
   $('#form123').html(data)};              

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `data` object to include three properties, one for the serialized form and the others for the samples.

```
data: {
  formData: $("#form123").serialize(),
  sample1: sample1,
  sampleTwo: sample2
}
```

**Update**: In light of this solution's not working in your case, here is an alternative.

Since the result of [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is to turn its input into standard URL-encoded form such as `prop1=val1&prop2=val2`, you could append your additional variables to the output string. For example,

```
var formData = $("#form123").serialize() + '&' + sample1 + '&' + sample2;
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: formData,
  ...
});
```

However, this is somewhat kludgy, not readily extensible to larger numbers of additional parameters, and should not be done without sanitizing the values of `sample1` and `sample2`.

Depending on your situation this may be a workable solution, but I think that [Robert Levy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22676922/607408) of adding the data to hidden inputs in your form is probably a better one.

Comment: I tried your solution: sample1 and sample2 values are correct but formData (the model) now returns all null values.

Comment: Off the top of my head without seeing more of the site I'm not sure why that would be, though a simple solution might just be to declare `var formData = $("#form").serialize();` before the ajax call, and then pass that to the `formData` element of the `data` object.

Comment: Using the var formData, as you suggested, I can see that (before entering the ajax) it has all the correct values but they all arrive as null at the controller action. If I use the original example, they arrive at the controller with all correct values.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully this or @Robert's suggestion will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to merge multiple objects together:

```
data: $.extend(
   $("#form123").serialize(), 
   { something: 'else'}, 
   { and: 'even', more: 'things'}
)
```

Alternatively, just add the other fields to your form as `<input type='hidden' ...>` elements

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this alternative option cause it is an external script file and there is no way to access the model in there. I need the text of the selected item in a DropDownListFor and the model is bind to its value, which I also need. I can get the text in the javascript but cannot pass it together with the model in ajax

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Michael's answer, you could also do it via routing:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "Action/Controller/" + sample1 + "/" + sample2,
   data: $("#form123").serialize(),       
   cache: true,
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'html',                                
   success: function (data) {                       
   $('#form123').html(data)};              

});
```

Using this approach, you would need to define a route so you can interpret the extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner, more "MVC" solution is to use [Ajax.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

There's no need to write any custom javascript. Simply setup your View to be something like:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new {@param1 = "aaa", @param2 = "bbb"}, new AjaxOptions(){HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "#section1"})){
<div id="#section1">

..... put your form controls here . . . 

</div>
}
```

When submitted, the form will send an ajax request to the server containing both the supplied parameters + any form data. The response replaces the contents of #section1 with the result (as specified by the UpdateTargetId option).

For this to work, your controller action would be something like

```
public PartialViewResult Action(string param1, string param2, ViewModel model)
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider this "more MVC", it just has an additional dependency on Microsoft's AJAX tooklit which is totally unnecessary

Comment: I'd take the hit of an additional dependency that supports routing over hardcoding URLs in custom javascript any day.

Comment: You can get routing without the Microsoft AJAX dependency.  Take a look at @Url.Action( ... )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if those **vars** are server-side variables or client-side.

In either way, I think you should embed them in your FORM, so they get serialized and sent along with the rest of the form.

For server side / Razor variables

```
<input type="hidden" id="var1" name="var1" value="@sample1" />
```

For client side / JS variables

```
<input type="hidden" id="var2" name="var2" value="" />

$('#var2').val(var2); //before sending your form of course!
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i had this same problem and this is the first page that appear searching for it so i want to share other way of doing it.

In the url section use

```
url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { sample1= "XXX", sample2 = "XXX" })'
```

Keep in mind that the variables sample1 and sample2 cannot be js inside the new {} because it is an htmlHelper and are in diferent contexts, but you can use a Viebag/ViewData or razor variables to set the sample1/2 values or just use static text like in my example.

The rest of the code stays the same.

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { sample1= "XXX", sample2 = "XXX" })'
   data: $("#form123").serialize(),       
   cache: true,
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'html',                                
   success: function (data) {                       
   $('#form123').html(data)};              

});
```

In the controller:

```
public async Task<XXX> Action(Model data, string sample1, string sample2)
```

I hope it helps.